# Is it possible to test Responsive Web Design application with Sahi?

Tags: responsive-design, automated-tests, sahi

I'm testing a Responsive Web Design application now. I'm doing Manual testing on Firefox, Chrome and IE using Web Developer Tool.

I like to automate the testing. Is it possible to automate Responsive Web Design with Sahi?

Answer (score 2):

If you dont need some visual confirmation, you can simply test with phantomjs. Have a look at http://sahi.co.in/w/sahi-headless-execution-with-phantomjs and add the line "page.viewportSize = { width: 1000, height: 1000 };" to your sahi.js to execute phantomjs. You can set the width and height to any value you want.
To improve this, create different phantomjs scripts with different viewport sizes and add multiple phantomjs launcher in your browsers.xml. Like phantomjsMobile, phantomjsTablet ...

If you **need to see** the results, not just test their functionality, taking screenshots with phantomjs is also possible. https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Screen-Capture

Answer (score 1):

Sahi_Pro V5.0 released with additional functionality to test Responsive Web Design application. 
Download Sahi_Pro V5.0 from the following page:

http://sahi.co.in/downloads-archive/

Comment: I'm using Sahi Java Driver. Can you please provide me some java code example in Sahi for changing Browser Resolution like 300x300 so that I can test Responsive Wed Design app.

Comment: I don't want to use sahi script. Instead I like to use Java in Sahi Web Test Automation Tool.